# Make Graph Not Dirty on Update of Unbound DAC in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have an unbound filter DAC in a graph in Acumatica (22.107.0022). I'm trying to make the graph not dirty when fields in this DAC are updated. I also want the save button at the top of the screen to not be enabled after any of the unbound fields are updated (if the graph was not already dirty).

I've successfully achieved this in another customization project that I compiled in a later release of Acumatica (23.107.0022). But using the same method in version 22.107.0022 still shows the save button as enabled.

Here is what I tried in the graph:

```
public class MyGraph : PXGraph<MyGraph, MasterDAC>
{
    . . .

    [PXHidden]
    public class FilterDAC : IBqlTable
    {
        #region Field1
        [PXString(IsUnicode = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Field 1")]
        public virtual string Field1 { get; set; }
        public abstract class field1: PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<field1> { }
        #endregion
    }    

    public PXFilter<FilterDAC> Filter;

    public virtual IEnumerable filter()
    {
        FilterDAC filter = this.Filter.Current;
        yield return filter;
        this.Filter.Cache.IsDirty = false;
    }

    . . .
}
```

Is there any way to make the graph not dirty, or is this behavior dependent upon the release or version of Acumatica?